# Is "actual hands-on" SYNONYMOUS with "hands-on experience"?

Tags: synonyms

I need to confirm if the word can be used as an **alternative** to: EXPERIENCE.

Example sentence:

> These days, working people not only need **experience**, but also soft skills.

Or

> These days, working people not only need **hands-on experience**, but also soft skills.

Or (I want this to work):

> These days, working people not only need **actual hands-on**, but also soft skills.

I don't want to repeat experience, experience, and then experience again in an essay. So I am asking if "actual hands-on" is grammatical.

P.S.: Since I already know the hands-on experience word, please don't insist that ONLY two synonyms are fine for better essay.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why "soft skills" (of communication, commitment, teamwork, etc.) should be contrasted with "[practical, hands-on] experience". Some soft skills are effectively "innate" (you've either got them or you haven't), but mostly they're things you can significantly improve with experience.

Comment: The "Soft skills" aspect is a different topic. Sorry, lets talk about the synonyms of the "experience.

Comment: should also need is wrong in your sentences.

Comment: Edited it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are synonymous with each other, they aren’t exactly synonymous with experience though.

**Hands-on experience** and **actual hands-on mean**:

> knowledge or skill that someone gets from doing something rather than just reading about it or seeing it being done

([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hands-on-experience), definition for actual hands-on similar but taken from another dictionary)

Experience definition:

> (the process of getting) knowledge or skill from doing, seeing, or feeling things

([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/experience))

So whilst **experience can be gained from seeing something hands-on experience and actual hands-on can only be gained from doing it**, not just seeing or reading about it.

Comment: They are not synonyms. One is an adjective and the other is a noun.

Comment: @Lambie, I think they can all be used in an essay without considering their in-depth definition hehe. Thx so much, now I know.